# OpenID Connect Front-Channel Logout: How to behave on missing user-session or session mismatch?

Tags: openid-connect

Let's say, an RP (Relying Party) triggers a Front-Channel Logout, but the OP (OpenID Provider) has no session stored to match this logout request or a mismatch occurs.

How should the OP handle this logout request in the case of:

- no user logged in for HTTP-session, but logout request is valid (i.e. `id_token_hint` is known)
- no user logged in for this HTTP-session and logout request is invalid in terms of i.e. `id_token_hint` was known but session has expired
- logged in user, but logout-request can't be matched to logged in user (`id_token_hint` not matching)